# Laptop fan buzzing sound

Tags: audio, fan

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is my computer fan so loud?](https://superuser.com/questions/2370/why-is-my-computer-fan-so-loud)

3 days ago my HP dv6 fan started making buzzing sound. At first it was un-noticable but yesterday It got a bit louder and my notebook started vibrating a little bit and It can be felt with hands. It is very hot here in my country and room temps are around 34C, sometimes doors and windows also get hard but then they settle down automatically.Should I be worried about laptop's this condition. Here is link to sound file.

http://www.mediafire.com/?g34a13e536ew7cf

Please help.. If somebody faced this situation before assist me what to do..

Comment: Also see: http://superuser.com/questions/99662/computer-fan-starting-to-make-noises-cant-unscrew-the-laptop-got-a-solution?rq=1, http://superuser.com/questions/352030/how-to-clean-a-fan-on-a-hp-6715s-notebook-without-taking-it-out

Answer (score 1):

34 Cel Degree doesn't make the fan run crazy, it's might be your computer running overload by some virus. Try to use Task manager to figure it out.

Sometimes, when you live in a dirty country, you have to clean your Fan frequently. Like me, I live in India and I have to clean it every 3 month.

Comment: which notebook do you have. My notebook is just 2 months old

Comment: My one is Sony, if your notebook is only 2 months old then it's software problem.